# Npm paypal button: createOrder is not a function

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I was using without a problem the component Paypal button v2 since yesterday and all of sudden after changing a simple irrelevant line in my code, I experiencing problem with it. After undoing the change I made I still get the following error:

```
Error: createOrder is not a function
render/createOrderFn<
src/index.tsx:191

 188 | const createOrderFn =
 189 |     amount && !createOrder
 190 |         ? (data: any, actions: any) => this.createOrder(data, actions)
> 191 |         : (data: any, actions: any) => createOrder(data, actions);
     | ^  192 | 
 193 | return (
 194 |     <Button
```

I don't have any createOrder function in my program or createOrderFn component, so I don't know what the error means.

Has anybody every experienced something similar?

Here is how I render the paypal component:

```
return (
        <div
            style={{
                position: 'absolute', left: '50%', top: '15%',
                transform: 'translate(-50%, -15%)'
            }}
        >
            <PayPalButton
                amount={state.total}
                // shippingPreference="NO_SHIPPING" // default is "GET_FROM_FILE"
                onSuccess={(details, data) => {
                  alert("Transaction succesful.")
                  state.user.cart.linesItems = [];
                  state.user.cart.subtotal = 0;
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(state.user));
                  saveUserCart(state.user);
                }}
                options={{
                    clientId: "sb"
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function call might also trigger if `amount` is undefined/false for some reason at that point. You should add logging to determine what exactly is happening.

In any case, it looks like you're using an unofficial react module; try with the new [@paypal/react-paypal-js](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/) instead.